# Send list of object from a web service to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to send a List of objects back from a web service in an activity to another activity but I get `NullPointerException`.

I think I have a problem in array list and data witch come from web service

```
    private void parsAndSendTheAudiDbAlbumDetail(String response) {

    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TheaudiodbAlbums theaudiodbAlbums = gson.fromJson(response, TheaudiodbAlbums.class);

        List<AlbumDetail> albumDetails = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < theaudiodbAlbums.getAlbum().size(); i++) {

            AlbumDetail detail = new AlbumDetail();
            detail.setStrAlbum(theaudiodbAlbums.getAlbum().get(i).getStrAlbum());
            detail.setStrArtist(theaudiodbAlbums.getAlbum().get(i).getStrArtist());
            albumDetails.add(detail);
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("classList",(Serializable)albumDetails);
        returnIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
        }
```

This is the First Activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


        //Set data to AlbumFragment

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

        List<AlbumDetail> albumDetailList= (List<AlbumDetail>) bundle.getSerializable("classList");

        Toast.makeText(this,albumDetailList.get(0).getStrAlbum(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

and the class is :

```
public class AlbumDetail implements Serializable {
private String strAlbum;
private String strArtist;

public String getStrAlbum() {
    return strAlbum;
}

public void setStrAlbum(String strAlbum) {
    this.strAlbum = strAlbum;
}

public String getStrArtist() {
    return strArtist;
}

public void setStrArtist(String strArtist) {
    this.strArtist = strArtist;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using getIntent(); would provide the intent that is used to start the activity. For getting the intent data from result of an activity, use the intent provided in the method parameter.. as

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
```

Instead of

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```